# $\frac{P(x_1 \mid y, s = 1) \dots P(x_n \mid y, s = 1) P(y \mid s = 1)}{P(x \mid s = 1)}$ indicates that naive Bayes learners are global learners?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, papers, naive-bayes, selection-bias

I am currently studying the paper [*Learning and Evaluating Classifiers under Sample Selection Bias* by Bianca Zadrozny](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.92.170&rep=rep1&type=pdf). In section **3. Learning under sample selection bias**, the author says the following:

> We can separate classifier learners into two categories:
>
> - local: the output of the learner depends asymptotically only on $P(y \mid x)$
> - global: the output of the learner depends asymptotically both on $P(x)$ and on $P(y \mid x)$.
>
> The term "asymptotically" refers to the behavior of the learner as the number of training examples grows. The names "local" and "global" were chosen because $P(x)$ is a global distribution over the entire input space, while $P(y \mid x)$ refers to many local distributions, one for each value of $x$. Local learners are not affected by sample selection bias because, by definition $P(y \mid x, s = 1) = P(y \mid x)$ while global learners are affected because the bias changes $P(x)$.

Then, in section **3.1.1. Naive Bayes**, the author says the following:

> In practical Bayesian learning, we often make the assumption that the features are independent given the label $y$, that is, we assume that
> $$P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n \mid y) = P(x_1 \mid y) P(x_2 \mid y) \dots P(x_n \mid y).$$
> This is the so-called naive Bayes assumption.
> With naive Bayes, unfortunately, the estimates of $P(y \mid x)$ obtained from the biased sample are incorrect. The posterior probability $P(y \mid x)$ is estimated as
> $$\dfrac{P(x_1 \mid y, s = 1) \dots P(x_n \mid y, s = 1) P(y \mid s = 1)}{P(x \mid s = 1)} ,$$
> which is different (even asymptotically) from the estimate of $P(y \mid x)$ obtained with naive Bayes without sample selection bias. We cannot simplify this further because there are no independence relationships between each $x_i$, $y$, and $s$. Therefore, naive Bayes learners are global learners.

Since it is said that, for global learners, the output of the learner depends asymptotically both on $P(x)$ and on $P(y \mid x)$, what is it about $\dfrac{P(x_1 \mid y, s = 1) \dots P(x_n \mid y, s = 1) P(y \mid s = 1)}{P(x \mid s = 1)}$ that indicates that naive Bayes learners are global learners?

---

EDIT: To be clear, if we take the example given for the local learner case (section **3.1. Bayesian classifiers**), then it is evident:

> Bayesian classifiers compute posterior probabilities $P(y \mid x)$ using Bayes' rule:
> $$P(y \mid x) = \dfrac{P(x \mid y)P(y)}{P(x)}$$
> where $P(x \mid y)$, $P(y)$ and $P(x)$ are estimated from the training data. An example $x$ is classified by choosing the label $y$ with the highest posterior $P(y \mid x)$.
>
> We can easily show that bayesian classifiers are not affected by sample selection bias. By using the biased sample as training data, we are effectively estimating $P(x \mid y, s = 1)$, $P(x \mid s = 1)$ and $P(y \mid s = 1)$ instead of estimating $P(x \mid y)$, $P(y)$ and $P(x)$. However, when we substitute these estimates into the equation above and apply Bayes' rule again, we see that we still obtain the desired posterior probability $P(y \mid x)$:
> $$\dfrac{P(x \mid y, s = 1) P(y \mid s = 1)}{P(x \mid s = 1)} = P(y \mid x, s = 1) = P(y \mid x)$$
> since we are assuming that $y$ and $s$ are independent given $x$. Note that even though the estimates of $P(x \mid y, s = 1)$, $P(x \mid s = 1)$ and $P(y \mid s = 1)$ are different from the estimates of $P(x \mid y)$, $P(x)$ and $P(y)$, the differences cancel out. Therefore, bayesian learners are local learners.

Note that we get $P(y \mid x)$. However, in the global case, it is not clear how we get $P(x)$ and $P(y \mid x)$ (as is required for global leaners) from $\dfrac{P(x_1 \mid y, s = 1) \dots P(x_n \mid y, s = 1) P(y \mid s = 1)}{P(x \mid s = 1)}$.